# Php Sql Get value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm doing some database query and I want a automatic system but I encounter this when getting the list of tables with the query.

```
SHOW TABLES ;
```

Using Php to get this function returns the array of tables now just the values like Person.
It is posible to get only the result?

```
   $rows = Array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  array_push($rows, $row);
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Result

```
[{"0":"Company","Tables_in_database":"Company"},{"0":"Education","Tables_in_database":"Education"},{"0":"Health","Tables_in_database":"Health"},{"0":"Person","Tables_in_database":"Person"},{"0":"Personal","Tables_in_database":"Personal"},{"0":"Skill","Tables_in_database":"Skill"}]
```

I only want the values: Company, Education, Health, ETC.

Comment: I didn't understand your question. What exactly you want?

Comment: I did not understand it either!

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: I updated the question with the result guys. Thanks for reply

Comment: `array_push($rows, $row['Tables_in_database']);`?

Comment: Thanks Alan it works the selection

Answer (score 0):

`$row` is an array containing all the columns in the results. Since you just want one column, select it explicitly.

```
array_push($rows, $row['Tables_in_database']);
```